# Is there a way to get the result of the last operation into a variable

Tags: laravel, read-eval-print-loop, tinker

Sometimes when using the `php artisan tinker` console I do something like the following:

```
$int->groupBy('tracking_code')->toArray();
```

instead of:

```
$a = $int->groupBy('tracking_code')->toArray();
```

If the operation is very complex and/or is on lots of records, it can be a pain to  repeat with the variable assignment. So my question is whether the result of the last command is stored anywhere so I can manipulate it without having to wait for the operation to complete a second time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tinker uses PsySH as the REPL.

```
$a = $_
```

`$_` is a magic variable that holds the result of the last successful execution.

You can find documentation for PsySH on its website:

[PsySH](https://psysh.org/)

Comment: I have a blog post that goes over Tinker and PsySH features (and the exact use case you are asking about): [asklagbox - blog - Tinker all the things](https://asklagbox.com/blog/tinker)